# Search engine used by Django website and Zinnia?

Tags: django, search-engine, zinnia

What search engine app does the Django project uses itself in their website?

The search form in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/

Is that search engine good for blogs?  Or the one used by Zinnia (what app is that?) is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DjangoProject.com uses Elastic Search:

https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com#documentation-search

Elastic Search is a full-featured, modern search engine, and what you can do with it is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. You can find out more about it here:

https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch